# How to tag the Cloud Build

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting Github Actions to build a small web app.  I'm looking to add the GitHub commit hash to the underlying Cloud Build history to make tracing of a release easier.

Given my config for the GitHub workflow below, a build entry is started in the history in the Cloud Build dashboard of the same GCP project.  I don't have control of the build project since Firebase Hosting controls this behind the scenes (I can only see the Build history).

deploy.yaml

```yaml
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy production on 'main' branch merge
"on":
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHECKMATE_PROD }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: XXX
```

Is there a way I can add the tag in the `Tags` field?  From my GitHub actions config?

[image]